# C++ "return" the result of an expression

Tags: c++, c++98

Is there any difference between the evaluation of expressions between the two return statements below, based on the extra parenthesis?

```
    return a++ *(-b+123.456)/999.12344;
```

vs

```
    return (a++ *(-b+123.456)/999.12344);
```

Programming Language C++ 
Standards CPP 98'ish (Before C++11)

Hope the question is clear. Expectation is to evaluate the expression in full.

Comment: Did you want to use ++a instead?

Comment: @drescherjm • Not enough context.  `a` could be a reference parameter or a global or a member variable.

Comment: The missing context is which value you want. There is no reason to suggest `++a` here.

Comment: I was trying to answer 2 questions. 1) what is the reason for the a++ (given the missing context) 2) why does the OP want to add the (). Although I could easily be on the wrong track.

Comment: I think the specific logic of the arithmetic expression is only a distraction.

Comment: Apart from the other disadvantages discussed in the answers: it makes `return` look like a function...

Answer (score 5):

Sloppy speaking `x` is the same as `(x)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256162/4117728) for the "striclty speaking" answer ;). Adding parentheses around the full expression does not change anything about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

PS: It has an obscure impact on return value optimization (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256162/4117728) for the details). Though, it definitely has no impact on the value that is returned.

Comment: Regarding your "PS", indeed it does; see my answer for a demonstration.

Comment: "obscure impact on return value optimization" - I'm not sure that it's that obscure!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit meh now my answer is nothing more than a collection of links to your answer

Comment: @user463035818: And what a wonderful index it is. Have an upvote!

Comment: @user463035818 I wasn't going to say it :P

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any difference between the evaluation of expressions between the two return statements below, based on the extra parenthesis?

No; the parentheses are completely redundant *in this case*.

---

An expression `expr` is actually not the same as an expression `(expr)`, and you can observe this with `return` because copy/move elision is inhibited in the latter case:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    T() { std::cout << "T()\n"; }
    T(const T&) { std::cout << "T(const T&)\n"; }
    T(T&&) { std::cout << "T(T&&)\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "~T()\n"; }
};

T foo()
{
    T t;
    return t;
}

T bar()
{
    T t;
    return (t);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test 1\n------\n";
    foo();
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Test 2\n------\n";
    bar();
}
```

Output:

```
Test 1
------
T()
~T()

Test 2
------
T()
T(T&&)
~T()
~T()
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60af7f01cc02b572))

You can probably observe the same result before C++17 because compilers have always tried to optimise return values. Even in your standard, C++98, you can probably observe that the copy constructor isn't invoked in the first case.

But, hey, none of that is relevant for a simple arithmetic expression.

Comment: Even worse: `auto baz() { T t; return (t); }` will return a dangling reference...

Comment: @Aconcagua Does not seem to be true: https://godbolt.org/z/6thI89, you need `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: OK, thanks, Holt. Still there *is* such a situation where you can get a dangling reference by just adding the parentheses... Do you happen to know where the standard defined this?

Comment: @Aconcagua I think here is a good start: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.auto.deduct-5

Answer (score 3):

There are differences. Using parentheses **will** obviate *return value optimisation*.

If, for example, `a` and / or `b` were objects with all suitable operators overloaded, then using parentheses could suffer you the overhead of an object value copy.

For plain-old-data there is no difference, subject to the C++11 abomination

```
decltype(auto) ub_server() { int a; return (a);}
```

which actually gives you a *dangling reference*.

In summary: Don't use the enclosing parentheses unless you want some of the above behaviour, and possibly only then with a supporting comment.

Comment: Is this abomination behavior still present in C++14 and/or C++17?  (Enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.)

Comment: @Eljay: Yup. Would be a breaking change if it wasn't. Enough rope to blow your whole leg off.